# C#. Синхронизация многопоточной записи в сокет

Tags: c#, многопоточность, async-await

Имеется программа - сокет сервер, использующий стороннюю библиотеку. Есть класс, который занимается отправкой сообщений. Работает он асинхронно. Вот как выглядит функция отправки сообщений:

```
public async void SendMessageAsync(Socket socket, Message message)
{
    await socket.SendAsync(message);
}
```

В этом классе есть еще функции по выборке определенных сокетов и все они ссылаются на эту функцию.

Сам сокет и функция `SendAsync` из пространства имен сторонней библиотеки. В этой библиотеке отправка сообщений сокету сделана так, что одновременно нельзя отправлять несколько сообщений, иначе вылетает исключение.

Функция `SendMessageAsync` часто вызывается из разных потоков и бывают случаи одновременной отправки разных сообщений одному и тому же сокету.

Допустим к серверу подключено 100 сокетов. Все они находятся в одном списке (`ConcurrentDictionary<Socket, Session>`), доступ к этому списку может получить любой поток. Инициировать отправку сообщения может любой поток. Допустим, сейчас идет отправка сообщения сокету #1. И в этот же момент запускается функция по таймеру, которая отправляется всем сокетам другое сообщение. Как можно сделать синхронизацию отправки сообщений для сокета #1, при этом не мешая отправке другим, сохраняя асинхронность?

Comment: *"Функция `SendMessageAsync` часто вызывается из разных потоков и бывают случаи одновременной отправки разных сообщений одному и тому же сокету."* -- а разве у каждого потока не свой экземпляр сокета? Судя по вашему коду сокет не является общим ресурсом, соответственно и синхронизировать доступ к нему не нужно. Или может быть покажете чуть более полный код?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В случае когда один и тот же экземпляр сокета берут несколько потоков, просто синхронизировать отправку в методе `SendMessageAsync` действительно не получится. Можно сделать обертку над классом `Socket` и синхронизировать доступ уже внутри обертки. Дополнительно нужно подключить библиотеку [Nito.AsyncEx](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Nito.AsyncEx/), которая предоставляет функциональность [асинхронных локов](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/wiki/AsyncLock).

```
using Nito.AsyncEx;

public class SynchronizedSocket
{
    private readonly AsyncLock _lockObject = new AsyncLock();
    private readonly Socket _socket;

    public SynchronizedSocket(Socket socket)
    {
        if (socket == null)
        {
            throw new AgrumentNullException(nameof(socket));
        }

        _socket = socket;
    }

    public async Task SendMessageAsync(Socket socket, Message message)
    {
        using (await _lockObject.LockAsync())
        {
            await socket.SendAsync(message);
        }
    }
}
```

Не забудьте добавить обертки для других методов `Socket`, которые вы используете. При необходимости их также можно синхронизировать.

При этом основной класс будет содержать словарь оберток:

```
ConcurrentDictionary<SynchronizedSocket, Session>
```

---

Пара замечаний не по теме вопроса:

- используйте `async void` **только** для событий и методов, имеющих событийную семантику, плюс не забывайте оборачивать все тело таких методов в `try/catch`, поскольку иначе вы рискуете а) не узнать о том, когда завершится метод, б) обрушить приложение или просто не узнать о том, что внутри метода произошло исключение (зависит от того, в какой контекст выбросится исключение)
- ваш изначальный метод `SendMessageAsync` можно немного оптимизировать, убрав ожидание и модификатор `async`:

  ```
  public Task SendMessageAsync(Socket socket, Message message)
  {
      return socket.SendAsync(message);
  }
  ```

Подробнее можно узнать [в этом докладе](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lh8cT6qI-nA).

Comment: А будет ли рациональным решением в обертке сокета использовать библиотеку Microsoft.Tpl.Dataflow, а именно `BufferBlock<Message>` ?

Comment: @DimaGvozdev без архитектурных изменений - ее там просто негде использовать.

Comment: @DimaGvozdev а вносить архитектурные изменения когда ошибка нормально устраняется без них - странно.

Comment: @DimaGvozdev к сожалению, с DataFlow я не работал. Предложенное изменение действительно является минимальным и необходимости в чем-то другом я не вижу.

Comment: У меня в классе для отправки сообщений есть метод, который выбирает нужные сокеты по условию и в цикле вызывает функцию `SendMessageAsync`. Выглядит это дело вот так:
    foreach (KeyValuePair<Socket, Session> row in Users)
            {
                if (predicate(row))
                    SendMessageAsync(row.Key, message);
            }
Как в этом методе лучше вызывать функцию `SendMessageAsync` чтобы она выполнялась асинхронно? Функцию сделал так, как вы написали `public Task SendMessageAsync(Socket socket, Message message)`

Comment: Создайте `List<Task>`, в цикле добавляйте таски в этот список `tasks.Add(SendMessageAsync(row.Key, message));`, а после цикла ожидайте завершения всех тасков: `await Task.WhenAll(tasks);`. Соответственно метод, содержащий этот цикл, должен в свою очередь стать асинхронным и должен быть вызван правильным образом.